# Why oninput function not work under JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

My HTML code:

```
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label for="input-text-help" >Select Vendor 
    </label>

    <select name="vname" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Vendor</option>

    <?php
    foreach($Fetchvendors as $Fetch){
                                               ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $Fetch->id;?>"><?php echo $Fetch->name; ?> 
    </option>       
                                <?php   
                                }
                                ?>
                                </select>

                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <label for="input-text-help"> Date</label>

                            <input type="text" name="date"  id="datepicker" class="form-control">

                          </div>
                            <table class="table">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-left:500px;">**Add More**</i>
                                    <thead>
                                            <th>Material Name</th>
                                            <th>Quantity</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                            <tr >
                                <td>
        <select name="mname[]" class="mname">                              
                <option value=""> Select Material </option>
                <?php
                foreach($FetchMateril as $Fetch){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $Fetch->id;?>"><?php echo $Fetch->mname; ?></option>      
        <?php   
        }
        ?>
        </select>
                            </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="qty[]" class="quanitity" id="qty" placeholder="Material Unit">
                                    <!--
                                <select name="qty[]" class="quanitity">

                                    <option>Select Quanitity</option>
                                    <?php for($i=1;$i<=50;$i++){?>
                                    <option><?php echo $i;?></option>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </select>
                                -->
                                </td>
                                <td>
    <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" id="**price**" *oninput="calculate()"*>
                        <input type="text" name="Totalprice[]" id="Totalprice" >

                        &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="input-text-help" style=" margin-left:300px;" >
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                </div>
```

In my html code have a option to add more row for multiple insert, When i click on add more option it add one row by javascript. in my input tage price **oninput** call calculate function, where calculate function calculate two input field and return in third field.

It Work on row one but in second row totalprice not work mean calculate not return any value in third field.

My question can `oninput="calculate()"` function under JavaScript like

My code when I am click **Add more** option

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //alert();
             var i = 0;
            $(".fa-plus").click(function(){
                $(".table").append('<tr><td><select name="mname[]" 
    class="mname"><option>Select Material</option><?php foreach($FetchMateril as 
    $Fetch){?><option value="<?php echo $Fetch->id;?>"><?php echo $Fetch- 
    >mname;?></option><?php }?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" 
    ></td><td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value=""></td> 
    </tr>');

            i++;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My calculate function

```
    function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('qty').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('price').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('Totalprice'); 

    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    //alert(myResult);
    document.getElementById('Totalprice').value = myResult;

    }
```

Comment: generate element with different ids it will surely work  ,when you add more to create input, in that case each element has same id, that is why on calculate() it takes the first element's id

Answer (score 0):

Try This May this will help you

```
$('#price').on('keyup', function(){
   var myBox1 = document.getElementById('qty').value; 
   var myBox2 = document.getElementById('price').value;
   var result = document.getElementById('Totalprice'); 
   var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
   document.getElementById('Totalprice').value = myResult;
});
```

Comment: Not Work my code work first time but in second time not work